# Cleaning up promises (flattening and error handling)

Tags: javascript, promise, when-js

I'm using the `when` library and have some code like this:

```
when.join(
    database.then(function(db) {
        return db.collection("incidents");
    }).then(function(col) {
        return col.idExists(incidentId);
    }),
    database.then(function(db) {
        return db.collection("images");
    }),
    elib.uploadToS3(pic.path, 'image_uploads/' + id, pic.type)
).spread(function(exists, images, url) {
    if(!exists) {
        throw new Error("Incident id does not exist");
    }

    console.log("Image sucessfully uploaded to: ", url);
    return images.insert({
        _id: id,
        size: pic.size
    });
}).then(function() {
    console.log("At this point, it's totally succesfully recorded in the database!")
});
```

The code is reasonably readable, but the logic is:

1. Ensure the incidentId is valid
2. Get the image table
3. Upload the image to S3

All these 3 can happen at the same time. Step 1 and 2 both share the same 'database.then', so I'd like to use that, but I don't know how to flatten promises.

If there's any problems (including an incidentId not being valid), I should call `elib.deleteFromS3('image_uploads/' + id);`

If that was all successful, I'm ready to "commit" by adding a new entry in the database:
`images.insert({ _id: id, size: pic.size })`

If that works, we're done. If it doesn't, I still need to delete from S3 again.

Any help on keeping this readable while satisfying the error handling and 'database.then' reuse would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Step 1 and 2 both share the same 'database.then', so I'd like to use that, but I don't know how to flatten promises.

You're already reusing same `database` promise twice (and that's great), you're just after two different mappings of that promise, and it's very logical to use two different `then` calls in such case. Trying to do that with one, wouldn't be reasonable, and clearly won't give you any benefit.

I also wouldn't mess with S3 until I'm sure there's reason for operation.
So I would do 1 and proceed with 2 & 3 only after id exists:

```
database.then(function(db) {
  return db.collection("incidents");
}).then(function(col) {
  return col.idExists(incidentId);
}).then(function (exists) {
  if (!exists) throw new Error("Incident id does not exist");
  return when.join(
    database.then(function(db) {
      return db.collection("images");
    }),
    elib.uploadToS3(pic.path, 'image_uploads/' + id, pic.type)
  ).spread(function(images, url) {
    console.log("Image sucessfully uploaded to: ", url);
    return images.insert({
      _id: id,
      size: pic.size
    })(null, function (err) {
      return elib.deleteFromS3('image_uploads/' + id).then(function () {
       throw err;
      });
    });
}).then(function() {
  console.log("At this point, it's totally succesfully recorded in the database!")
});
```